# Twitter Ruby Gem Failing To Update when Reply

Tags: ruby, twitter

I'm using the twitter gem found here: http://sferik.github.io/twitter/

I have some code that looks like:

```
@twitter_client.update(tweet_string, :in_reply_to_status_id => 402712877960019968)
```

Which generates the error:

```
./twitter.rb:68:in `update': wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)
```

However, I'm looking at the documentation here: https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/Update.md
Which says:

```
client.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!", :in_reply_to_status_id => 402712877960019968)
```

When I remove the :in_reply_to_status_id, it works fine. I believe you can see the method here (Line 128): https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/0d23c5ed65a7e7728cd096d611e5edeecdbc6e79/lib/twitter/rest/tweets.rb

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work using the latest gem version and putting the in reply status in a hash:

```
client.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!", {:in_reply_to_status_id => 402712877960019968})
```

Give that a try and let me know if that works

Comment: I got the error to go away, but I'm still not getting the reply to show up on twitter. Does twitter acknowledge the reply and display it in the interface?

Comment: When I ran it, it returned a simple tweet object. Maybe print out the return object and see what it got back. Not sure if there is way to print out errors. Also double check that your twitter app has write access. Mine didn't by default.

Comment: I got a simple tweet object back too. I'll dig into this further and update with what I find.

Comment: So what is happening is that twitter isn't processing tweets/replies in real time (obviously because of scale), and so when I reply it doesn't show up at the same time the tweet as being a reply. But if I wait, in some cases at least, a couple hours it appears again.